# Intellij 2022.3, search plugins, connection issue

Tags: intellij-idea, connection

Intellij 2022.3, search plugins, connection issue.

Settings > Plugins > Marketplace.

```
Marketplace plugins not loaded.
Check internet connection and refresh
```

Refresh: same error

Internet no problem.

chrome browser: no problem such as visiting StackOverflow,
installing Microsoft visual studio 2022: no problem, the installer downloaded lots of files.

Windows 10 firewall: turned off Defender Firewall, did not help.

Comment: Please ensure that [proxy is properly configured in the IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-http-proxy.html). If the problem remains, contact JetBrains support team at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new for further processing

Comment: use mobile hotspot, no proxy. It works for other internet connections. thanks.

Comment: Tried the latest android studio, same error.